# Async with HTTPClient

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, async-await

I'm calling a WEB API with HTTPClient in an App for WP8. When I click a button I look for an user credentials and if it's ok go to the main page.
This is my code:

**Calling Method**

```
private async void BtnLogin_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var user = new User();

    if (user.IsAuthenticated(tbUserName.Text, tbPassword.Text))
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml"));
    }
}
```

**User Class**

```
public class User
{
    private bool? _isAuthenticated;
    public bool IsAuthenticated(string _userName, string _password)
    {
        return (bool)  (_isAuthenticated ?? (_isAuthenticated = AuthenticateAsync(_userName, _password).Result));
    }

    private static async Task<bool> AuthenticateAsync(string userName, string password)
    {
        var baseUrl = string.Format(Constant.AuthenticateAPIUrl, userName, password);
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl) };
            var result = await client.PostAsync(baseUrl, new StringContent("")).ConfigureAwait(false);                
            result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem is when await is executed, it blocks the App and never returns.

I try a lot of distinct codes but I think I'm lost now!!.

Comment: You can't do that.  Never use `.Result` to synchronously wait for an async task.

Comment: I tried before without .Result but in that way when I do " if (user.IsAuthenticated(tbUserName.Text, tbPassword.Text))" How can I expect to be true or false???

Comment: I got it I think! I have to make the call this way:  if (await user.IsAuthenticated(UserName, Password)), correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Calling `Task<T>.Result` or `Task.Wait` on the UI thread can cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I explain in full on my blog.

To fix it, replace every use of `Result` or `Wait` with `await`

```
public async Task<bool> IsAuthenticatedAsync(string _userName, string _password)
{
    return (bool) (_isAuthenticated ?? (_isAuthenticated = await AuthenticateAsync(_userName, _password)));
}

private async void BtnLogin_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var user = new User();

    if (await user.IsAuthenticatedAsync(tbUserName.Text, tbPassword.Text))
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml"));
    }
}
```

Other notes:

- Don't ignore compiler warnings. Your original code was informing you that your `async void BtnLogin_OnClick` method didn't have an `await`.
- Follow the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

Comment: It works for me!! thanks, but I had to delete "await" from the IsAuthenticatedAsync method